# Not able to run theharvester on kali linux. Fatal exception: Pycurl: Link time version is older than compile time version

Tags: pycurl, kali-linux

I tried running theharvester on my kali machine but then I get an error, "Fatal exception: pycurl: libcurl link-time version (7.65.3) is older then compile-time version (7.66.0). Wfuzz needs pycurl to run." I reinstalled pycurl and Wfuzz with pip and still the error persists. Please help me on this.

Answer (score 2):

It's easy bro, if you want to solve it just open your kali machine and just type following command:

```
sudo apt-get install python-pycurl
```

It will install pycurl packages what you needed then you can locate and run theHarvester easily,.....